# Multiple routes to the same View class in Vaadin Flow 14

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to reuse a View implementation and define multiple, parametrized, routes to it.

Is this actually even possible? I have tried the below but always hit Error 404. It's the `RouteParameters` that appear to be causing this.

```
Nav nav = new Nav();
RouterLink link1 = new RouterLink();
link1.setRoute(viewClass, new RouteParameters("entity", "e1"));
nav.add(link1);
RouterLink link2 = new RouterLink();
link2.setRoute(viewClass, new RouteParameters("entity", "e2"));
nav.add(link2);
```

Important: I do not want to show the route parameters in the URL.

Comment: >do not want to show the route parameters in the URL.
Why not?

Comment: @ollitietavainen Because the configuration data I want to share with the View class is sensitive. Thus, I do not want to put it in the URL.

Comment: If you want to use route parameters, you will see the route parameters in the URL. Maybe you need to rephrase your problem.

Comment: @ollitietavainen there is actually something confusing to me here: `RouteParameters` vs. `QueryParameters`... QueryParameters in the query (URL) makes sense, but what about RouteParameters? What's the relation between them?

Comment: Have you implemented HasUrlParameter in the class which has Route("entity") annotation?

Comment: @TatuLund I do implement `HasUrlParameter<String>` and no route path works when RouteParameters are provided. I am only getting 404, regardless of the URL I am manually filling in the address bar.

Comment: Dived deeper and it looks like `ConfiguredRoutes.getTargetRouteModelMap` returns null, but unsure what am I doing wrong / why doesn't it get set up properly.

Comment: I asked about HasUrlParameter interface as your should implement tat in target route, if you use url parameters there.

Comment: @TatuLund Right. I eventually determined that I had to do something like: `new RouteParameters("___url_parameter", "e1")`, so use `___url_parameter` instead of `entity`. Still, not the right solution for me, as I do not want to use URL parameters. The problem is that the routing is view class based and I cannot provide a flexible implementation this way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass information between two views, but you don't want to share this information in the browser (in the URL or otherwise). In this case, any parameters are simply the wrong solution - whether they are Route parameters (which look like http://my-app/p1/p2/p3) or Query parameters (which look like http:/my-app?p1=a&p2=b&p3=c) .

Comment: Instead, you can store this information in the session, a shared injected Bean with a common scope, or other means such as ComponentUtil.setData.

Comment: @ollitietavainen that won't work, because I will no longer be having control of the resulting View instance (i.e. I will not be able to associate a local bean instance with the View instance Vaadin is going to instantiate based on the class I provide), as I can only pass on its class and Vaadin takes care of everything, including the instantiation. Allowing only for a class to be given limits reusability a lot, or at least complicates things a bunch. If a View instance would be accepted, then things would be much different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to show the data in the URL, then you should be looking for other solutions than putting the values in route parameters.

If I understand you correctly, this *sounds* like a state management problem. There are many mechanisms for sharing state between views (including things like cookies and client-side storage), but since this is not information you want to share with the client you should be considering server-side state management options.

You aren't limited to Vaadin-specific solutions, but it does provide a few options. You can use the VaadinSession, although that will be shared between multiple browser windows so you could experience unexpected behavior if users have multiple windows open. If you're using Spring, you could define and inject a [@UIScope](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/integrations/spring/tutorial-spring-scopes) bean and store your state there. Because a new UI is created for every browser window, the state would be isolated. If you go down this path, be careful about injecting narrowly scoped beans into more broadly scoped beans.